# Webbrowser free for commercial use

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm using a Google Chrome Portable browser for my offline app. But I'm not sure if I can use it for commercial purposes. Please can anybody give advise if there's such a browser, that is completely free. Or is there really simple way how to create my own.. What I want is to show a html file in that browser. It doesn't need to have any address bar, etc. I've already searched how to create a browser, but I am not really good in programming languages, I only manage web pages, so I don't know which would be the best way.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not the only one searching for an answer https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xuyg5tSad08

This is the first answer I got when I searched a bit
"Google Chrome is totally free for commercial and personal use." I found this on http://www.technibble.com/google-chrome-portable-internet-browser/

Answer (score 1):

You can use it for commercial purpose as per their [EULA](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/privacy/eula_text.html). See point 21.

21. **Additional Terms for Enterprise Use**

    1. If you are a business entity, then the individual accepting on behalf of the entity (for the avoidance of doubt, for business entities, in these Terms, "you" means the entity) represents and warrants that he or she has the authority to act on your behalf, that you represent that you are duly authorized to do business in the country or countries where you operate, and that your employees, officers, representatives, and other agents accessing the Service are duly authorized to access Google Chrome and to legally bind you to these Terms.
    2. Subject to the Terms, and in addition to the license grant in Section 9, Google grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable license to reproduce, distribute, install, and use Google Chrome solely on machines intended for use by your employees, officers, representatives, and agents in connection with your business entity, and provided that their use of Google Chrome will be subject to the Terms.

August 12, 2010